# How to install pocketsphinx 0.1.15 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install pocketsphinx 0.1.15 on my ubuntu machine ubuntu16.04 .I used the command `pip install pocketsphinx` but it is throwing me error .I have added the error here. https://pastebin.com/raw/3125YWKF. Can anyone help me telling what is going wrong.I am using python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in the output reveals the culprit:

> deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_pulse.c:44:30: fatal error:
>   pulse/pulseaudio.h: No such file or directory

Looks like you need to install the `libpulse-dev` package to get this header file.